# How to select particular Row using Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, enzyme, jestjs

We are using Jest for UI TDD of React application.

We have following structure of component redering:

```
<Div>
  <Row>
   </Row>
   <ROW>
   <Row>
   <ROW>
      <Link> <Link> 
   <ROW> 
<Div>
```

We are trying to get Row with link.

We are trying following code.

```
const rowProps = wrapper.find(Row).at(0)
```

How to locate to row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find `Link` component - use @Tony answer.
But if you want to locate `Row` component, which contains `Link` component - use this code (it works only if you have one `Link` component inside mounted wrapper)

```
const rowWithLink = wrapper.find('Link').parent()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
const rowProps = wrapper.find('Row Link')
```

Comment: Whats row link is it class or id on that Row?

Comment: Row and Link are the components you have listed; with enzyme `find()` you can use Component Display name as a search criteria